# Does symmetry of the Green's function of some operator imply that the operator is hermitian?

Tags: greens-function, self-adjoint-operators

I know that if an operator $L$ is hermitian(self-adjoint), then its Green's function is symmetric, but is it true the other way?

In other words, is having a symmetric Green's function a necessary and sufficient condition for $L$ to be hermitian?

Comment: By symmetric, do you mean $$\mathscr{G}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \mathscr{G}(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x}) \quad\forall \mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\overline{D}\subseteq \Bbb R^n$$ where $D$ is the domain where $\mathscr{G}$ is determined from $L$?

Comment: @Daniele Tampieri Yes, indeed

Answer (score 1):

Nope, There are even finite dimensional counterexamples! So the definition of the Hermitian conjugate of an operator is
$$\forall\vec x, \vec y\hspace{5mm}\langle L^\dagger x, y\rangle=\langle  x, Ly\rangle$$
Let the inner product be defined via a positive definite matrix $G$ (not to be confused with Green's functions which are represented by $L$'s entries.)
$$\langle x, y\rangle:=\vec x^{*T}G\vec{y}$$
A few lines of handwriting shows that the Hermitian conjugate is now given by
$$L^\dagger=G^{-1}L^{*T}G$$
Now your question becomes: Does $L=L^T$ imply $L^\dagger=L$?

"Nope!" is justified by the counter example:
$$G=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0& 0\\
0 & 1 & \alpha\\
0 & \alpha & 1
\end{pmatrix}\hspace{3mm}|\alpha|<1$$
$$L=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0& 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I would change $G$ to $M$ or something similar and make $L$ invertible in the counterexample, but these are matters of taste. Your answer gives good intuition. (+1)